# How to print a linked list that is made up of another linked list of string?

Tags: c++, list

I have decided to use the STL list, although our instructor has been teaching us one that is made from the book. I made this change because the header file from the book is not working with me, most probably my fault. So, after researching  online, I have tried my best to understand how the iterator of the STL list works. The following is the code that I made to print the linked list x defined by type `list<list<string>>`.

```
  list < list <string>> x;

while (!inData.fail())
{
    //...
    string str(cstr);//cstr at this point is the sorted string
    bool match = false;
    list <string> inner_list;
    inner_list.push_back(str);
    list<list <string>>::const_iterator cit;
    for (cit = x.begin(); !match && cit !=x.end(); advance(cit,1))
    {
        if (*cit == inner_list)
        {
            inner_list.push_back(temp2); //temp2 is unsorted string
            match = true;
        }
    }

    if (match ==false) x.push_back(inner_list);
```

}

```
//printing


list<list <string>>::const_iterator it; 
    list<string>::const_iterator it2;
    for (it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++)
    {
        for (it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); it2++)
        {
            cout << *it2 << " ";
        }

    }
```

I am getting a list iterator dereferencing error, but I have no clue why. I would appreciate any help or hints. And if anything is unclear or needs explanation please tell me.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @BoBTFish I am getting the error in run time; it says "list iterator not dereferencable" and it makes a reference to the list header with line 210

Comment: What is the call stack when exception/assertion is thrown. Is any other function working on `x` while this loop is running?

Comment: Move the definition of the iterators into the according loop headers, which makes it clearer that their scope is just that of the loop. That said, your code is incomplete so it's not suitable to reproduce the issue, but it doesn't look wrong either, so I guess the cause is the code that you didn't show.

Comment: Hmm. There's nothing obviously wrong with the snippet you posted, and I can turn it into a complete working example [here](http://ideone.com/uLNVn4). Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am adding another snippet

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Done, I think that the error might be from "*cit == inner_list"

Comment: @user29568 You never check whether `cit` reaches `x.end()`. Since you never increment `i` you'll move past the end.

Comment: @molbdnilo I believe that was the error, thank you

Comment: *"I have decided to use the STL list, although our instructor has been teaching us one that is made from the book."* Well done. You are right and your instructor is wrong :) (if he actually thought the one in the book was better than the standard one from an engineering POV, rather than just trying to teach you something about data structure basics).

Comment: @ChristianHackl :) I would appreciate it if you could link me to a website or reference that gives detailed explanation on how the STL list data structure works and how its created. I checked Stroustrup's book but it didn't cover it in depth.

Comment: @user29568: cppreference.com is the best free online reference I am aware of. Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list. Notice that when using C++ standard constructs, you mostly *should* forget how they work internally, i.e. your focus is on interface, not implementation. Documented **runtime complexity is part of the interface** of C++ standard containers, which helps you in choosing the right container class (however, you will mostly just use `std::vector` anyway). And of course, this more or less forces compilers to provide optimal implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code. Hope this will help you. Thanks.

```
typedef long long ll;

ll N,M;
string str;
list<string> innerList;
list<list<string> > Data;

cin >> M; // M holds the no. of nodes containing linked list of strings //
for(ll i=0; i<M; i++){
    getchar();
    cin >> N; // No. of strings containing in inner linked list 
    getchar();
    for(ll i=0; i<N; i++){
        cin >> str;
        innerList.push_back(str);
    }

    Data.push_back(innerList);
    innerList.clear();
}

// print data //

for(list<list<string> >::iterator it = Data.begin(); it!=Data.end(); it++){
    for(list<string>::iterator iit = (*it).begin(); iit!=(*it).end(); iit++){
        cout << (*iit) << "  " ;
    }
    cout << "\n";

}
```